# How to force cordova to recompile added plugins?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

It seems `cordova` caches compiled plugins, when i change the source code of plugins (`.java` files on windows), the only way to force cordova to recompile the plugin is to remove and then add that plugin again, which is a pain .
Is there any way to clean cordova cache or force it to recompile added plugins ?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out for an hour why the java wouldn't recompile.  I guess Cordova decided it wasn't important to recompile source files.  It's a shame they're missing such rudimentary features.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you tell me where did you find that `cordova` caches compiled plugins? I was looking for the plugin recompile for days but couldn't find an answer, there is very poor (no) documentation on how does the cordova compile process work? It is such a pain!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not afaik, the only workaround I've found is to use a before_prepare script to remove and add the plugin every time you prepare the app:

```
/
|--hooks/
   |--before_prepare/
      |--000_RefreshPluginXXX.sh
```

000_RefreshPluginXXX.sh:

```
!#/user/bin/env bash
cordova plugin rm yourPlugin
cordova plugin add yourPlugin
```

[See here for details](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/templates/hooks-README.md). Hope that sh file works under windows environment, otherwise you can do it with a `.bat` file.

Beaware that this is going to remove, download and reinstall the specified plugins for every platform every time that you prepare your app (prepare occurs when you build/emulate/compile)

Comment: it will redownload the plugin which means all my changes will be lost :|

Comment: In fact you can do whatever you want with this kind of scripts, so for example an idea would be to save your plugin locally in another folder, edit and make changes from there and replace last order of the script with `cordova plugin add path/to/your/local/folder`

Answer (score 16):

Afaik there's no way to recompile the original files.

The quickest and most dirty way (still the best for quick checks) is to change the files under

e.g. (Android)

platforms/android/src/YOUR_PACKAGE/FILE_TO_CHANGE

that way it's automatically recompiled.

Obviously this file can be easily deleted or overwritten so it's just a way to quickly test SMALL changes.

Comment: I'm making (small) changes to plugins in `platforms/android/src/path/to/package/path/to/file`, but `cordova build android` won't actually output a new APK. Any idea why?

Answer (score 13):

From cordova>=6.0 you can install and link your local plugin path to the project instead of copy it so it will recompile each time you build.

```
cordova plugin add /local/path/to-plugin/ --link
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#cordova-plugin-command

Comment: I wish I found this comment 5 hours ago!

Comment: Also, on windows you may need to run this command as administrator, otherwise you may get "EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink.." error

Comment: This work for me on Linux. * I first backup the plugin folder * cordova plugin rm my-plugin * cordova plugin add /some/path/outside/plgin/folder --link  * and I kept it out of the plugin folder, that saved me some problems..