# Modify cordova plugin - app not see changes

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I need to modify cordova-plugin-media, but when I run app with `ionic cordova run android` my changes are not applied.

How should I modify and run plugin correctly?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/26481507/488666

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer.

- cordova files should be edited in `/plugins` folder, not in `/node_modules`
- after editing, I should do: `ionic cordova platform rm android` and `ionic cordova build android`

After that modifications work.

Answer (score -1):

You should paste some code, showing the code of app module and config.xml.

But basically you should only do:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
npm install --save @ionic-native/media
```

And then add your plugin to the project into file
App.module.ts:

```
import { Media } from '@ionic-native/media';
...
providers: [
  ....
  Media,
...
]
```

And that's it, then you should be able to use the functionalities inside your components.